Extraction of 3 TTL signals from LCD pins of Kintex 7 KC705 FPGA BOARD
I'm using Kintex7 kc705 FPGA board to generate 3 TTLS signals (bits) in order to control a RF switch. Next I want to extract those three signal from the LCD pins (J31 on the FPGA board), which contains 14 pins (13 is the GND and the 14th the VCC 5V pin). I tried to use three pins and I wrote my contraints file as follows ( my 3 signals are  ctrl_1 , ctrl_2, ctrl_3 ):
set_property PACKAGE_PIN Y10 [get_ports {ctrl_1[0]}] #1 on LCD PORTS
set_property IOSTANDARD  LVCMOS15 [get_ports {ctrl_1[0]}] 
 
set_property PACKAGE_PIN AA10 [get_ports {ctrl_2[0]}]  #3  on LCD PORTS
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS15 [get_ports {ctrl_2[0]}]


set_property PACKAGE_PIN AB10 [get_ports {ctrl_3[0]}]  #9  on LCD PORTS
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS15 [get_ports {ctrl_3[0]}]

############################ DEBUG D'UNE ERREUR ######################################
####################################################################################3
set_property SEVERITY {warning}[get_drc_checks NSTD-1]
set_property SEVERITY {warning}[get_drc_checks UCIO-1]

The problem is that I receive this error whenever I try to generate my bitstream:

[DRC NSTD-1] Unspecified I/O Standard: 3 out of 18 logical ports use I/O standard (IOSTANDARD) value 'DEFAULT', instead of a user assigned specific value. This may cause I/O contention or incompatibility with the board power or connectivity affecting performance, signal integrity or in extreme cases cause damage to the device or the components to which it is connected. To correct this violation, specify all I/O standards. This design will fail to generate a bitstream unless all logical ports have a user specified I/O standard value defined. To allow bitstream creation with unspecified I/O standard values (not recommended), use this command: set_property SEVERITY {Warning} [get_drc_checks NSTD-1].  NOTE: When using the Vivado Runs infrastructure (e.g. launch_runs Tcl command), add this command to a .tcl file and add that file as a pre-hook for write_bitstream step for the implementation run. Problem ports: ctrl_1, ctrl_2, and ctrl_3.
[DRC UCIO-1] Unconstrained Logical Port: 3 out of 18 logical ports have no user assigned specific location constraint (LOC). This may cause I/O contention or incompatibility with the board power or connectivity affecting performance, signal integrity or in extreme cases cause damage to the device or the components to which it is connected. To correct this violation, specify all pin locations. This design will fail to generate a bitstream unless all logical ports have a user specified site LOC constraint defined.  To allow bitstream creation with unspecified pin locations (not recommended), use this command: set_property SEVERITY {Warning} [get_drc_checks UCIO-1].  NOTE: When using the Vivado Runs infrastructure (e.g. launch_runs Tcl command), add this command to a .tcl file and add that file as a pre-hook for write_bitstream step for the implementation run.  Problem ports: ctrl_1, ctrl_2, and ctrl_3.

Can anyone help me to fix those errors please ?
I tried to change the IOSTANDARD from LVCMOS15 to LVCMOS 18,25,33 but it didn't work.
This is my entity part of the program :
entity gtwizard_0_exdes is
generic
(
    EXAMPLE_CONFIG_INDEPENDENT_LANES        : integer   := 1;
    EXAMPLE_LANE_WITH_START_CHAR            : integer   := 0;    -- specifies lane with unique start frame ch
    EXAMPLE_WORDS_IN_BRAM                   : integer   := 512;  -- specifies amount of data in BRAM
    EXAMPLE_SIM_GTRESET_SPEEDUP             : string    := "TRUE";    -- simulation setting for GT SecureIP model
    STABLE_CLOCK_PERIOD                     : integer   := 16; 
    EXAMPLE_USE_CHIPSCOPE                   : integer   := 0           -- Set to 1 to use Chipscope to drive resets);
port(
    Q0_CLK1_GTREFCLK_PAD_N_IN               : in   std_logic;
    Q0_CLK1_GTREFCLK_PAD_P_IN               : in   std_logic;
    Q2_CLK1_GTREFCLK_PAD_N_IN               : in   std_logic;
    Q2_CLK1_GTREFCLK_PAD_P_IN               : in   std_logic;
    DRP_CLK_IN_P                            : in   std_logic;
    DRP_CLK_IN_N                            : in   std_logic;
    RXN_IN                                  : in   std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    RXP_IN                                  : in   std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    TXN_OUT                                 : out  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    TXP_OUT                                 : out  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    clk_out1                                : out  std_logic; 
    ctrl_1                                  : out  std_logic ; 
    ctrl_2                                  : out  std_logic ; 
    ctrl_3                                  : out  std_logic );


Please post the entity section of your top level VHDL, so that we can see the list and names of your IO pins.

Hello mr @Mikef , i edited my message and i added the entity part of the prpgram ,

Are you able to provide a complete small design that reproduces the issue? Someone can attempt to reproduce if you post a complete design and constraints file. See minimal reproducible example  Also include the full part number you are using for the build, in your post.

The message is indicating that the FPGA has 18 top level ports and 3 of them have no location (PACKAGE_PIN) and no IOSTANDARD constraint.  You need to provide both constraints for each top level IO of the FPGA.
Like you did here for these three.
set_property PACKAGE_PIN Y10 [get_ports {ctrl_1[0]}] #1 on LCD PORTS
set_property IOSTANDARD  LVCMOS15 [get_ports {ctrl_1[0]}] 
 

set_property PACKAGE_PIN AA10 [get_ports {ctrl_2[0]}]  #3  on LCD PORTS
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS15 [get_ports {ctrl_2[0]}]


set_property PACKAGE_PIN AB10 [get_ports {ctrl_3[0]}]  #9  on LCD PORTS
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS15 [get_ports {ctrl_3[0]}]

Signals ctrl_1[x],ctrl_2[x],ctrl_1[x] appear to be arrays/vectors so they are multiple physical IO associated each.  Every element of the array/vector needs to have both constraints.

i tried to change this part to: [get_ports {ctrl_1}] and [get_ports {ctrl_2}] and [get_ports {ctrl_3}] since thel all contain only one element, but still showing the same error indicating that the prblem is in ctrl_1, ctrl_2 and ctrl_3!

Take a look at your post synthesis schematic (use f4 in vivado when the synthesized design is open) Check to see that the ctrl_1, ctrl_2, ctrl_3 ports are present in the schematic. The tool may have removed them, in that case it would may complain about your constraints.

I've already checked that , all my output signals exists in the schematic, only my three control signal " ctrl_1 , ctrl_2 and ctrl_3 ) pose a problem in the bitstream generation , saying that they are unconstrained and don't have a specified IOSTANDARD!! even that i constrained my signals and i specified the IOSTANDARD !!
